# UDP handling multiple clients

Tags: c++, networking, udp

I cant seem to figure out how to do the next step for my UDP server. So far one client connects and then it sends data back and forth but when another client connects the server will take data from the new client and send it to the other.

I was going to check if the message that has been received is from a new client or not, if it is then give that client an identifier that the server uses to do some processing. Is that the correct way to do it? If so how do you do it? I know that recvfrom has "sockaddr *from" field which I assume fills that field with the data of the client but how do I use that data?

Thanks

Comment: You could record each clients ip by using recvfrom then check where the incoming data comes from, mapping the call to the correct client. Or atleast something like that=)

Comment: I was trying to do that but its contained within an "IN_ADDR" struct and I dont know which member is the IP

Comment: Use TCP. UDP is a connectionless protocol.

Comment: this is for a networked game which UDP is better suited for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sockaddr_in saddr;
int length = sizeof(saddr);
int read = recvfrom(your_socket, buff, 4096, 0, (sockaddr*)&saddr, &length);
if(read != -1) {
   // now saddr contains the address of the client
   // the g_addr is a previously captured client address
   if(saddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = g_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr) {
      // returning client?
   } else {
      // not yet seen client, so store address
   }
}
```

Comment: I have that part working its how I compare "saddr" to the other clients?

Comment: better use `struct sockaddr_storage` - it is guaranteed to hold all sizes of valid sockaddrs.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is connection-less.  Try using TCP.  Why did you decide to use UDP?  What are your constraints?

Comment: If it is only question/answer, there is no need for a connection. If ssomething gets lost, the client will hopefully notice it and retry on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The address in the recvfrom function will be filled with the source information from the client.  In the case if udp it will give you address and port, which for IPv4 can easily be converted to a long long and stored as an identifier.  IPv4 is 4 bytes + port 2 bytes.  You will need to cast the pointer to sockaddr_in and then get the values of sin_port and sin_addr.

Comment: IP addresses are shared - because of limitation for the range of addressess.

Comment: @EdHeal - Right but I don't see how that becomes an issue if the identifier is stored as: |---4 bytes IP ---|-- 2 bytes port -- |--- 2 bytes nothing --- |.   In a NAT situation you don't use UDP to communicate with the server.

Comment: Why not? If you have a UDP port forwarding, even that will work.